# Bare infinitive with exceptions

Tags: gerund-vs-infinitive, bare-infinitive, infinitive-constructions, perfect-infinitive

Reading the sentence:

> "We were still talking about what we should do when we heard the children shouting".

in the above sentence, why don't we write "heard the children shout", as the verb '**hear**' takes a bare infinitive without 'to'?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. 'He heard the children shouting' conveys a continual shouting. 'He heard the children shout' conveys a single shout.